# Finding a way to replace a column in an np.ogrid with a different formula for a specific value of the iterable

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, iterable

```
    a,b=np.ogrid[0:n:1,0:n:1]
    A=np.exp(1j*(np.pi/3)*np.abs(a-b))
    a,b=np.diag_indices_from(A)
    A[a,b]=1-1j/np.sqrt(3)
```

is my basis. it produces a grid which acts as an n*n matrix.

My issue is I need to replace a column in the grid, say for example where b=17.

I need for this column to be:

```
    A=np.exp(1j*(np.pi/3)*np.abs(a-17+geo_mean(x)))
```

except for where a=b where it needs to stay as:

```
    A[a,b]=1-1j/np.sqrt(3)
```

geo_mean(x) is just a geometric average of 50 values determined from a pseudo random number generator, defined in my code as:

```
    x=[random.uniform(0,0.5) for p in range(0,50)]

    def geo_mean(iterable):
       a = np.array(iterable)
       return a.prod()**(1.0/len(a))
```

So how do i go about replacing a column to include the geo_mean in the exponent formula and do it without changing the diagonal value?

Comment: Man, you really like `a` (and `b`)! It's somewhat confusing what is `a`...

Comment: `a` and `b` are just the dimensions of the grid that acts as a matrix i.e. an `a`*`b` matrix @AGNGazer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by saying that `diag_indices_from()` is kind of useless here since we already know that diagonal elements are those that have equal indices `i` and `j` and run up to value `n`. Therefore, let's simplify the code a little bit at the beginning:

```
a, b = np.ogrid[0:n:1, 0:n:1]
A  = np.exp(1j * (np.pi / 3) * np.abs(a - b))
diag = np.arange(n)
A[diag, diag] = 1 - 1j / np.sqrt(3)
```

Now, let's say you would like to set the column `k` values, **except for the diagonal element**, to

```
np.exp(1j * (np.pi/3) * np.abs(a - 17 + geo_mean(x)))
```

(I guess `a` in the above formula is row index).

This can be done using integer indices, especially that they are almost computed: we already have `diag` and we just need to remove from it the index of the diagonal element that needs to be kept unchanged:

```
r = np.delete(diag, k)
```

Then

```
x = np.random.uniform(0, 0.5, (r.size, 50))
A[r, k] = np.exp(1j * (np.pi/3) * np.abs(r - k + geo_mean(x)))
```

However, for the above to work, you need to rewrite your `geo_mean()` function in a such a way that it will work with 2D input arrays (I will also add some checks and conversions to make it backward compatible):

```
def geo_mean(x):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    dim = len(x.shape)
    x = np.atleast_2d(x)
    v = np.prod(x, axis=1) ** (1.0 / x.shape[1])
    return v[0] if dim == 1 else v
```

Comment: I'm assuming here `a` is analogous with `r` and the `17`/`k` with `b`? So, for example, if i wanted to change a row I could switch the `r` and `k`? and to clarify, yes `a` and `b` are the row and column index respectively!

Comment: also, what is the need for the `r.size` command in the creation of `x`?

Comment: @Luke 1) I corrected the formula for `A[r, k]` to replace 17 with `k` (I did not notice that 17 was the value of `b` in *your* example). That is why one should avoid re-using variable names. 2) _"if i wanted to change a row I could switch the `r` and `k`?"_ - Yes! 3) About `r.size`... You should print `x` and you will see that it is a matrix of size `(n-1) x 50`. The point here is to perform operations vectorially. So, instead of generating a single vector `x` (of length 50), I generate `(n-1)` vectors and run `geo_mean` for all of them at once.